# How to display Bitmap Image in image control on WPF using C#

Tags: wpf, listview, bitmapimage

I want that when I double click on a row in `ListView`, it should display the `Image` corresponding to that row. This row also contains the path of the `Image`.

I tried the following but it displays the same `Image` for all rows because I have given the path for a specific `Image`:

```
private void ListViewEmployeeDetails_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    ImageSource imageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\northwindimages\king.bmp"));
    image1.Source = imageSource;
}
```

Please suggest something.

Answer (score 1):

They key is to retrieve the row index that was clicked, and get the image URL for that row.  Since you say you are clicking on the row, this can be done in a method similar to that below

```
private void ListViewEmployeeDetails_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) 
    {
        DataRow row = (DataRow)sender; //Get the row that was clicked
        string imageURL = row["imageUrl"].ToString();//Get the img URL for that row
        ImageSource imageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imageURL));
        image1.Source = imageSource; 
    }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This code assumes that your click event (ListViewEmployeeDetails) is assigned to the row, as indicated in your original post.  If so, then the 'sender' object represents the row that is clicked, and as shown, can be cast to a data row.  If the click event is not attached to the row, but rather a control IN the row..let me know and I can show you how to get the row from the control as well.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that:

1. The list you are binding to contains Elephant objects and,
2. You want the image to show Elephant.Picture whenever you double-click an item.

You can set the image from an event handler as follows:

```
private void ListViewEmployeeDetails_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
  var viewItem = sender as ListViewItem;
  if(viewItem!=null)
  {
    var elephant = viewItem.DataContext as Elephant;
    image1.Source = elephant.Picture;
  }
}
```

Note that it is important to only accept double clicks on the ListViewItem.

The above code assumes that elephant.Picture is of type ImageSource.  If it is something else you will have to convert it.  For example, if instead Elephant has a string "PicturePath" property, the image1.Source line would change to:

```
    image1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(elephant.PicturePath));
```