# Populating a listview with checkboxes from a XAML file

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, checkbox

I've got a listview that looks like this (except a Load button has been added since this screen shot was taken):

[Listview image](http://dinosaur-island.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Seeding-Plants.jpg)

Here's the XAML code:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="YoungPicCell">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Height="200" Width="200" Stretch="None" Source="{Binding YoungPic}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MediumPicCell">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Height="200" Width="200" Stretch="None" Source="{Binding MediumPic}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="AdultPicCell">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Height="200" Width="200" Stretch="None" Source="{Binding AdultPic}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="TerrainCell">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <CheckBox Content="Salt Water"  Name="SaltWaterCheckbox" IsThreeState="False" IsChecked="{Binding Saltwater}" />
            <CheckBox Content="Fresh Water"  Name="FreshWaterCheckbox" IsThreeState="False" IsChecked="{Binding Freshwater}" />
            <CheckBox Content="Grassland / Plains"  Name="GrasslandsCheckbox" IsThreeState="False"  IsChecked="{Binding Grassland}" />
            <CheckBox Content="Swamp"  Name="SwampCheckbox" IsThreeState="False" IsChecked="{Binding Swamp}" />
            <CheckBox Content="Tropical Forest"  Name="TropicalForestCheckbox" IsThreeState="False"  IsChecked="{Binding TropicalForest}" />
            <CheckBox Content="Forest"  Name="ForestCheckbox" IsThreeState="False" IsChecked="{Binding Forest}" />
            <CheckBox Content="Forest Edge"  Name="ForestEdgeCheckbox" IsThreeState="False"  IsChecked="{Binding ForestEdge}" />
            <CheckBox Content="Sand"  Name="SandCheckbox" IsThreeState="False" IsChecked="{Binding Sand}" />
            <CheckBox Content="Coastal"  Name="CoastalCheckbox" IsThreeState="False" IsChecked="{Binding Coastal}" />
            <CheckBox Content="River Border"  Name="RiverBorderCheckbox" IsThreeState="False" IsChecked="{Binding RiverBorder}" />
            <CheckBox Content="LakeBorder"  Name="LakeBorderCheckbox" IsThreeState="False"  IsChecked="{Binding LakeBorder}" />
            <CheckBox Content="Floodplain"  Name="FloodplainCheckbox" IsThreeState="False"  IsChecked="{Binding Floodplain}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="PlacePlantsCell">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <Label Margin="10"  Content="Random" HorizontalAlignment="Center" ></Label>
            <Slider Margin="10"  Width="190" Value="50" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" Maximum="100" TickPlacement="BottomRight"  TickFrequency="5"> </Slider>
            <Button Margin="10"  Content="Randomly Seed Plants" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Height="23" Name="SeedButton" ></Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<DockPanel>
    <Grid>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=lsvData, Mode=TwoWay}" Name="listView1">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="152" Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}"  />
                    <GridViewColumn Width="202" Header="Picture of Young Plant" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=YoungPic}" CellTemplate="{StaticResource YoungPicCell}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Width="202" Header="Picture of Medium Plant"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=MediumPic}" CellTemplate="{StaticResource MediumPicCell}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Width="202" Header="Picture of Adult Plant"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=AdultPic}" CellTemplate="{StaticResource AdultPicCell}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Width="202" Header="Terrain / Environments" CellTemplate="{StaticResource TerrainCell}" />

                    <GridViewColumn Width="202" Header="Place Plants" CellTemplate="{StaticResource PlacePlantsCell}" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
        <Button Content="New Plant"  DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"  Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="160,240,0,0" Name="NewPlant" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="NewPlant_Click" />
        <Button Content="Save" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"   Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="1099,240,15,0" Name="SavePlant" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="SavePlant_Click"/>
        <Button Content="Load" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="26,240,0,0" Name="LoadPlants" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Click="LoadPlants_Click" Width="75" /> 
    </Grid>
</DockPanel>
```

Here is the XML file that is being loaded when you click on the Load button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Plants>
<Species>
    <Name>Alethopteris</Name>
    <YoungPic>AlethopterisYoung.bmp</YoungPic>
    <MediumPic>AlethopterisMedium.bmp</MediumPic>
    <AdultPic>AlethopterisAdult.bmp</AdultPic>
    <Saltwater>true</Saltwater>
    <FreshWater>False</FreshWater>
    <Grasslands>False</Grasslands>
    <Swamp>False</Swamp>
    <TropicalForrest>False</TropicalForrest>
    <Forest>False</Forest>
    <ForestEdge>False</ForestEdge>
    <Sand>False</Sand>
    <Coastal>False</Coastal>
    <RiverBorder>False</RiverBorder>
    <LakeBorder>False</LakeBorder>
    <Floodplain>False</Floodplain>
</Species>
</Plants>
```

And, lastly, here's the relevant code behind:

```
      public PlantDisplay()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _wvm = new WindowViewModel();
        this.DataContext = _wvm;
    }

    public class LVData
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string YoungPic { get; set; }
        public string MediumPic { get; set; }
        public string AdultPic { get; set; }
        public bool SaltWater { get; set; }
        public bool FreshWater { get; set; }
        public bool Grasslands { get; set; }
        public bool Swamp { get; set; }
        public bool TropicalForrest { get; set; }
        public bool Forest { get; set; }
        public bool ForestEdge { get; set; }
        public bool Sand { get; set; }
        public bool Coastal { get; set; }
        public bool RiverBorder { get; set; }
        public bool LakeBorder { get; set; }
        public bool Floodplain { get; set; }
    }


    public class WindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        //called when a property is changed
        protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string PropertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
            }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<LVData> _plantList = new ObservableCollection<LVData>();
        public ObservableCollection<LVData> lsvData
        {
            get { return _plantList; }
            set { _plantList = value; RaisePropertyChanged("lsvData"); }
        }

        public void PopulateDataFromXML()
        {
            XDocument loaded = XDocument.Load(@"DinoIslandPlants.xml");

            var Plants = from x in loaded.Descendants("Plants")
                          select new
                          {
                              Name = x.Descendants("Name").First().Value,
                              YoungPic = x.Descendants("YoungPic").First().Value,
                              MediumPic = x.Descendants("MediumPic").First().Value,
                              AdultPic = x.Descendants("AdultPic").First().Value,
                              SaltWater = x.Descendants("SaltWater").First().Value 
                          };
            foreach (var _plant in Plants)
            {
                _plantList.Add(new LVData { 
                    Name = _plant.Name, 
                    YoungPic = _plant.YoungPic, 
                    MediumPic = _plant.MediumPic, 
                    AdultPic = _plant.AdultPic, 
                    SaltWater = Convert.ToBoolean(_plant.SaltWater) });
            }

            RaisePropertyChanged("lsvData");
        }

    }
```

I'm having two problems:

1. It's crashing on this line: SaltWater = Convert.ToBoolean(_plant.SaltWater) });
2. It's not loading the image of the plant, but rather is displaying the path string.

Any ideas, suggestions? Is the way I'm saving a boolean in the XAML file correct?

Comment: What is the error you get when it crashes for question 1?
As for question two im not sure how you plan to display the images but I am going to guess there is a problem with the path you are providing for the image. Also im not sure how binding the source of the image to a string will work out for you. Have a look at this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949779/how-to-display-bitmap-image-in-image-control-on-wpf-using-c-sharp

Comment: The error message is: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: Sequence contains no elements

Comment: I feel pretty good about the path. I've actually edited the path in the XML file for clarity, but it's the complete path starting at c:\\... and it works when I hard code it in.

Comment: What is the string path that is output when try to bind your image?

Comment: Where would I catch that in the debugger? You mean the path of the image(s)?

Comment: what is the value of `YoungPic` or any of the others after the LVData class is constructed? Catch it in the debugger at the line `YoungPic = _plant.YoungPic`

Comment: I think it's something with the XAML and not the path because it's not correctly displaying an image even when I hard code it.

Comment: Well this is very strange. The string has - somehow - added EXTRA BACKSLASHES!   _plant.YoungPic "C:\\\\Users\\\\FRED\\\\Desktop\\\\Dinosaur Island\\\\DinoIsland\\\\bin\\\\Debug\\\\Images\\\\AlethopterisYoung.bmp"

Comment: And, this is from the XML file: <YoungPic>C:\\Users\\FRED\\Desktop\\Dinosaur Island\\DinoIsland\\bin\\Debug\\Images\\AlethopterisYoung.bmp</YoungPic> -- Any idea how that could happen?

Comment: But here's what the listbox looks like now: http://www.dowce.com/~J8p

Comment: Ok i think this may be down to your xml to string assignment. Correct me if im wrong but I think you are putting the image path into the xml including the backslashes. Backslashes have a use in xml to denote the end of an item as in `<Student></Student>`. XML likely appended more backslashes on as that is one way for the parser to realize you are adding the backslashes as actual characters. If I were you I would just have my xml contain the image name. Then in your c# code assign the image path for that name to your string variable.

Comment: I was thinking along the same lines. But even when I just truncate everything down to just the image name (and I've copied the image into the /debug folder) it's still just printing the string and not displaying the image. I somehow think the problem is in the XAML code that sets up the listview. But what, exactly, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem regarding question 1 is that in your XML you have the item Saltwater.
In your code you have this line.

```
SaltWater = x.Descendants("SaltWater").First().Value
```

Notice the difference between SaltWater and Saltwater? If you fix your case I believe you will sort that problem.

I am not sure why .First().Value does not throw an exception. Maybe another person could answer that for you.

Comment: WOW! YEAH! YEAH! Yeah, that solved. Yeah, I'm an idiot. Boy, do I miss working with a team. Thanks!